# MVC in Java - Static controller?

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I have a number of different organisations, each of which is an instance of the `Organisation` class. This contains getters and setters for instance variables, the setters contain validation where appropriate. It also has a few other odds and ends - overwritten `toString(), equals()` and `hashCode()` for example.

I have `OrganisationView extends JFrame` which accepts an Organisation and displays it in the GUI, and includes listeners for the various functions.

I understand from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015813/what-goes-into-the-controller-in-mvc) how this should all fit together and work with `OrganisationController`.  What I'm not clear on is how many, if any, instances of `OrganisationController` I need.  Is it one per organisation, and storing the organisation it refers to as an instance variable?  Because it seems easier just to declare `OrganisationController` as `static` and call its methods directly from `OrganisationView` giving `OrganisationView` a method something like:

```
private boolean deleteButtonPressed(){
    return OrganisationController.deleteOrganisation(this.organisationDisplayed)
}
```

(and perhaps some other business logic, but that's by the by)

`OrganisationView`, by the way, is called each time that particular display is needed, and is passed the organisation to show.

My question is: If it is better to have a separate instance of `OrganisationController` for each `Organisation` then why?  It seems like an unnecessary amount of objects differing only in one instance variable.  Or are static controllers acceptable?

Comment: *"Static controller?"* - No

Comment: One controller, yes -- one instance. Static -- no, stay away from static anything it makes your code untestable.

Answer (score 0):

I would not make it static.  Use a singular controller and separate your views into directories.  Then you can organized each part accordingly.  You don't want to statically call the controller from the view.  You want each person who logs in to have their own instance.  Its simply a matter of separating out your views, models etc into separate folders and directories.  I'm actually working on a project right now where I do this.  I prepend each section with a keyword so as to keep it separate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Singleton` pattern to make sure that you only create one Controller && also access your controller in a **static** way.

I suggest you go for the enum implementation of Singleton which would be something like this

```
public enum OrganisationController{
   INSTANCE;

    // you can have fields
    private final example;
    // and also methods
    public boolean deleteOrganisation(Organization org){
    // do whatever here
    }
}
```

And you can invoke methods in a *static-looking* way

```
OrganisationController.INSTANCE.deleteOrganization(org);
```