# Proper pagination in c# by days in asp.net mvc environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

following scenario: 
I have x amount of elements with different dates.
I want to group those elements by date and display all elements for each day.
I want to display only 3 days per page.
Data is loaded on page refresh in a model.

What I am currently doing is load all elements in global.asax and have a list of objects which I am using for the relation between page id and date.
Now when I open a page with the id 1, I get all videos with the date according to the id.
Now when I add an item to the database, I'd obviously have to redo the whole process.
I was wondering if there was a better way to handle this whole thing.

Comment: You can begin by going here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

Well Marianne, there's no code in your question so nobody will be able to speak to that.

Your architecture could use a few tweaks.  Things that stick out are:

1. Using global.asax like a [controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015813/what-goes-into-the-controller-in-mvc).  That's a big no-no.  Use the controller as it's meant to be used.  If you absolutely need to cache some of the database results, take a look at [SqlDependency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).
2. If I am reading your post correctly, it would appear you are not using an [`WHERE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188047.aspx) clause in your sql query.  Another big no-no.

I bet with those two changes you would find most of your issue goes away.  If after making those changes you find you still have an issue, feel free to post a new question.

Comment: Everything's working just fine for now. But it feels rather hacky which is why I am asking. My code works as intended whether its beautiful or not. I probably didnt express my problem very well. I am not using global.asax as a controller. I am using it to set the static page to date relation which I am using to get the videos by date for a specific page.