# which is an accurately approach of mvc's component diagram?

Tags: model-view-controller

Learning about MVC pattern (the original pattern developed in 1978, not the MVC web application framework developed by Microsoft) I realised there's plenty of class diagram and another diagrams on the Internet, but there is not a component diagram, with their interfaces etc. I found only this one, and I wanted to know how accurate would be, and why there is almost 0 components diagram of the MVC pattern on the Internet:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Well, to be honest there is a lot of information of MVC which is confusing (as no one specifies which "iteration/version" of MVC they are talking). The components are the same: a model, a view, a controller.

But, multiples sources establish their relationships as they please. In the original MVC, as i understood, the controller arranges the views for the user to see and interact. The user input is processed by the controller, which sends updates to the model. The model, after changing state, sends signals to update the view accordingly (which means that the view is attached to the model). 
[image]

That component diagram you posted is not completely inaccurate. It is best to take a case study and analyze that component diagram. For example:

[image]

Some other questions might rise, like, how can the controller handle input if the user always interact with the view? Check [Details of implementation of MVC/ M(VC)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1016076/10467184)

Some other sources establish the controller as a "bridge" between model and view (web MVC) and the interactions are bidirectional (that is, the controller might also modify the views, the model might also send signals to the controller).